Why I'm getting error when using LIMIT with PDO
here my code :
$Limit=5;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table_name] ORDER BY [count] DESC LIMIT :limit';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', (int) $Limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results = $stmt->execute();

and here the error im getting :

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY090]: Invalid string or buffer length: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid string or buffer length

Any idea what im doing wrong?

You only get this error when you use LIMIT :limit?

Have you tried setting the PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES option explicitly?

yes, if i remove the LIMIT, i got no error,
how to use "PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES"?

$db->setAttr(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::setAttr()  does not seems to help :/

Sorry, it's setAttribute

now getting the error i had before about "Invalid string or buffer length"

I wonder if this has something to do with FreeTDS. I think most use the ODBC driver for SQL-Server.

try this query using top
$Limit = 5;
$sql = 'SELECT TOP :limit * FROM [dbo].[table_name] ORDER BY [count] DESC';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', (int) $Limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results = $stmt->execute();


still getting same error :/
